# Using where clause in caml query

Tags: mysql, xml, caml, form-designer

I want to do select all from item where Title equal to logInUser (which is current login user name).

In my code i have created : `var logInUser = context1.get_web().get_currentUser();`

But this doesn't work.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',readyFunction);

function readyFunction()  {
   getCurrentLoginUser();
   getCurrentLoginUserDetails();
}

function getCurrentLoginUser() {
   context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   web = context.get_web(); 
   currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
   currentUser.retrieve();
   context.load(web); 
   context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded,onQueryFailed);
}

function getCurrentLoginUserDetails() {
   context1 = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   oList = context1.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employee Annual Leave Records');
   var logInUser = context1.get_web().get_currentUser();
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml(   
      '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' + 
      '<Value Type=\'Text\'>' + logInUser + '</Value></Eq></Where>' +
      '</Query></View>'     
    );
    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context1.load(collListItem);
    context1.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceededD,onQueryFailedD);
}


function onQuerySucceeded(sender , args) { 
   var user = web.get_currentUser();
   fd.field('Employee_x0020_Name').control().value(user.get_title());
}


function onQueryFailed(sender , args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());   
}


function onQuerySucceededD(sender , args) {

   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
       var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
       fd.field('Employee_x0020_Number').value(oListItem.get_item('Employee_x0020_Number'));
       fd.field('Employed_x0020_Date').value(oListItem.get_item('Employed_x0020_Date'));
     }
 }


function onQueryFailedD(sender , args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".